# Web scraper : problem installing chromium

Tags: laravel, web-scraping, chromium

**General Description :**

I have a Laravel application that scrapes a certain website, using Chromium for headless browsing.
So far I've been working on my localhost and things are going fine.

**The problem is :**

Trying to deploy this app on my hosting, I wasn't given the authority to install chromium.

**My question is :**

- Is there anyway to install chromium other than   `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` ?
- Can you recommend any other way to crawl the actual html of a page after being rendered ?

Comment: Have you tried just downloading the headless chrome driver instead of installing?

wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb